# Which works better Collapsible or Accordion to hide Answers?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hai i searched for the difference between Collapsible and Accordion, but cannot find an answer. The both are working similar. Is Collapsible deprecated?
I have done code in Collapsible but it is not good looking. Which works better Collapsible or Accordion in mobile view.

```
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"><style> * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
} .column {
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
  padding: 5px;
} .row::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
} .collapsible { background-color: #808080; padding: 18px; width: 70%; border:none; } .content { padding: 0 18px; display: none; overflow: hidden; background-color: #f1f1f1; } </style><button type="button" class="collapsible">Open Answers</button> <div class="content">
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
  <p>Q1 : Apple<p>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
  <p>Q2 : Orange<p>
</div></div>
</div><script> var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible"); var i; for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) { coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() { this.classList.toggle("active"); var content = this.nextElementSibling; if (content.style.display === "block") { content.style.display = "none"; } else { content.style.display = "block"; } }); } </script>
```

Picture of my result and what i need.[image: Please Look on the Image.]

Please help, i barely know coding.

[image: Collapsible deprecated Image?]

Comment: Same concept....different name is all

Comment: That deprecation info in the picture is just for the tag. Collapsibles/accordions are an UI pattern on many platforms. It is just saying that you should use a more specific tag for your question.

Comment: It's all the same concept. This is the native solution for example: https://jsfiddle.net/pdt8fc60/

Comment: @JensIngels, thanks for that, I learned something new today!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no difference between collapsible and accordion.

Both are terms for an UI pattern where you can open or close (or show/hide or reveal/hide) something.
Typically, they are used in overview and detail situations like FAQs or hidden spoilers

You might argue that an accordion is made up from multiple collapsibles...

In your code it looks like you implemented this UI pattern yourself and called it a collapsible.
Other available implementations in JS and CSS libraries may use other names for the very same UI pattern.

As @JensIngels pointed out in the comments there is even a native standard implementation with good support in modern browsers. It is called detail and summary:

```
<details>
    <summary>Some details</summary>
    <p>More info about the details.</p>
</details>
```